# button_Click event never hit

Tags: master-pages, pageload, buttonclick

I have a web application utilizing master pages. For some reason, when I add a buttonclick event, the method is never hit. The page goes through the normal page_load events. How do I get my button click event to fire? Previously, This worked just fine, now this is happening in my whole application where the !page.IsPostBack always evaluates false from a button_Click

I have tried adding script Handlers and that doesnt seem to help

in the UI page:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="btn btn-primary" 
OnClick="putAccoutDetail" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" />
```

in the CodeBehind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Session["Authenticated"] == null || 
   Session["Authenticated"].ToString() != "true")
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
        }
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["UserID"] != null)
            {
                UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
                getUserData(UserID);
            }
        }

    }

 public void putAccoutDetail(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string statusMsg = string.Empty;
        var userInfo = db.UserMasts.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == UserID);
        if (userInfo != null)
        {
            userInfo.UserName = txtUserName.Text;
            userInfo.MilEmail = txtEmail.Text; 

            string base64 = Request.Form["imgCropped"];
            if (base64.Length > 0)
            {
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64.Split(',')[1]);
                String fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png";
                userInfo.PhotoPath = fileName;
                ImagePhoto.ImageUrl = "/Images/Users/" + userInfo.PhotoPath;
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Users/" + fileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    stream.Flush();
                }
            }
        }

        try
        {
            dHelper.LogAction("Update User Detail : " + userInfo.UserName);
            db.SubmitChanges();

            statusMsg = "Successfully Updated";
            lblstatusMsg.Text = statusMsg;
            lblstatusMsg.Visible = true;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            statusMsg = "Update Failed";
            lblstatusMsg.Text = statusMsg;
            lblstatusMsg.Visible = true;
        }            

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the form had unhandled ASP validators on certain fields. I added a validation group to those and then handled them in the button_Click and all is working